# TFS Java SDK Native Library Exception in a web service deployed on Axis2-Tomcat7-Ubuntu platform

Tags: java, tfs, apache-axis, tomcat7

I'm trying to execute TFS Java SDK Api commands in an axis2 web service deployed on Tomcat7.

I successfully ran my small application on windows platform.

I want to run my web service on a Tomcat deployed on Linux.

I get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` (Exception):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentVariable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I defined `com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory` system property.
I modified `catalina.sh` to include `-D"com.microsoft...=/home/user/tfsbin"` line.
I can see that above system variable is defined on Tomcat Axis2 happiness page (It gives
information about VM parameters)

My linux is 32 bit intel machine so I chose linux\x86 as native library files (5 .so files)
I copied them to `/home/user/tfsbin` and set `com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory` to this folder.

I'm using Ubuntu, Oracle jdk7, Tomcat7, Apache Axis2 1.6.2. TFS SDK 11.0.0.1211

I still get that `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Great first question. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

Download TFS Java SDK (I used build 11.0.0.1212)

When you extract folders, you will see dist/native folder.
Copy this folder contents to
    home/user/native.
Then set the system property in setenv.sh like this:
    -Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=/home/user/native

Replace user in the paths above with your actual user name in linux.
DO NOT try to point to your actual operating system folder. TFS Java SDK automatically
selects proper os according to my experience.

Comment: if i want to connect to TFS online server is it necessary to set the system property?

Comment: is there another way to do this?

Comment: @mosaad: I'm not sure about the content of your question but the solution mentioned above is for using TFS Java API in a Tomcat deployed Java web application. You can use TFS Java API in a simple commandline Java application, too.

Comment: I was just interested to know if this could be done in another way for example using maven, but you are right it works fine with tomcat, thats what I am using right now.